# Advantage of using glMapBuffer

Tags: java, opengl

When I use `glMapBuffer` I get a float (byte) buffer as return type, which I can use to modify the data on the server side.

But is there any performance advantages of doing so?

I have an example

Approach 1:
I create a float buffer with vertex data and pass it to `glBufferData` directly.

Approach 2: 
I allocate space using `glBufferData` and I pass no data...
I get the reference to a float buffer...
I write the float values to it to... and I unmap the buffer.

What are the pros and cons of two approaches

Am I doing the same on both?

I think that second approach avoids duplicates of buffers.

Comment: There will most likely be differences in graphics cards and drivers. The only way to know for sure is to measure. But in general, `glBufferData` will probably perform better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two very related aspects to this:

1. Reducing memory usage.
2. Avoiding unnecessary copying of data, which can hurt performance.

Calling `glBufferData()` with data being passed in includes the following:

1. You allocate buffer memory to store your data.
2. You store your data in this buffer you allocated.
3. When you call `glBufferData()`, the OpenGL implementation allocates memory for the data.
4. The OpenGL implementation copies the data from your buffer into its own allocation.

Compare this with what happens when you do the same thing with buffer mapping:

1. When you call `glBufferData()`, the OpenGL implementation allocates memory for the data.
2. When you call `glMapBuffer()`, the OpenGL implementation returns a pointer to its memory.
3. You store your data in this memory.
4. You unmap the buffer.

If you compare the two sequences, you have an extra memory allocation in the first one, which means that it requires about twice the memory in total. And the OpenGL implementation has to copy the buffer data in the first one, which is not the case in the second.

In reality, things can get a bit more complicated. Particularly on systems that have dedicated graphics memory (VRAM), there might be more copies of the data. But the principle remains, you reduce extra memory allocations and copying.

Another aspect to keep in mind is what happens beyond the initial use of the buffer, if you want to modify the content of the buffer after it was already used. Again, `glMapBuffer()` will generally reduce the amount of extra data copying, but it might come at the price of undesired synchronization. So it could be more efficient to pay the price for an extra copy needed for `glBufferData()` or `glBufferSubData()` to avoid synchronization points.

If you have these more complex cases where you frequently modify buffer data, you really need to start benchmarking, and you have to expect differences between vendors. You can also look into schemes where you use buffer mapping, but use a pool of buffers you cycle through instead of a single buffer, to reduce/avoid the performance penalty from synchronization.

On top of this, if you work on devices where power/thermal considerations come into play, you may want to measure power usage in addition to just execution speed. Because the fastest solution might not necessarily be the most power efficient.

Comment: Creating a pool...doesn't mean switching states often?.. btw thanks

Comment: @YashwanthCB You'll need some calls for binding the buffers, but that's no big deal. The bigger downside of that approach is that you will of course use more memory again. So the advantage of using less memory goes away, but you may maximize efficiency by avoiding extra data copying.

Comment: @YashwanthCB: Note that this post is talking about how C/C++ interface with OpenGL. Once Java and its `ByteBuffer` types get involved, it starts depending on exactly how those `ByteBuffer` types work.

Comment: So how will it depend.I have tagged it as java. .I used bytebuffer. .so be clear in your explanation plz

Comment: I would hope that if you use a direct buffer (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html if you don't know what that means), there would be no extra copies caused by using Java. But I haven't verified that. In any case, everything in my answer still applies once the Java API call has been marshalled to its native implementation.